# Display list with heading in line

Tags: html, css

How to display the following code in line with a heading and one list per column?

I tried it with the following code and with a style-attribute `display:inline-block;` at the header tag but none of them worked for me.

Thanks for your help.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body style="display: inline-block"> 
    <div>
      <h2>Members</h2> 
      <ul>
        <li>person_1</li>
        <li>person_2</li>
        <li>person_3</li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>1st shift</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>person_1</li>
        <li>person_2</li>
        <li>person_3</li>
        <li>person_4</li> 
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <br style="clear:both"> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or floats would suffice for such a task. Although it would be wise to add a `div` wrapping them both to which you can apply a clear. The clear is necessary due to the fact using floats with remove the elements from the document flow. A clear will negate this problem and restore page flow.

Please find a rough dirty example below (minus the clear).

```css
.list{
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.list ul{
  margin: 0;  
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body style="display: inline-block"> 
    <div class="list">
      <h2>Members</h2> 
      <ul>
        <li>person_1</li>
        <li>person_2</li>
        <li>person_3</li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <h2>1st shift</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>person_1</li>
        <li>person_2</li>
        <li>person_3</li>
        <li>person_4</li> 
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <br style="clear:both"> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **OR** simply avoid all the mess with floats and simply use inline-blocks.

Comment: Yes, you can indeed. Although `inline-block' is not perfect as you will get a small space between elements that can break layouts where precise positioning is required. The nature of the two options are both flawed IMO.

Comment: Agreed. One of the fixes for the space is setting font-size to zero on the container, and then resetting it to the normal value in each box.

Comment: I've found the fix to be hit and miss. I wish there were a nicer solution as inline-block is so much easier to implement and use with no need for extra markup or clears. You can use the positioning of the closing tags on the elements to do a similar thing but I find it tedious, although perhaps I am just lazy.

Comment: @Doidgey Thanks for your fast and well explained answer.

Comment: @JohnDizzle Thanks for not even checking my answer which arrived roughly 3 minutes before the other and solves and explains everything with one line :D Ah, the injustice here...

Comment: @Doidgey Yeah, I hear you, everything seems like a hack. I guess they knew they'd introduce flex boxes so never bothered fixing it for real.

Comment: @Shomz Indeed! Flex is real nice and perfect for situations like this as it gives even more control over positioning with such ease. The only downside currently is patchy IE support with extra syntax needed. If you don't mind the fallbacks to cover yourself, it's quite usable right now.

Answer (score 2):

Your divs actually need to be displayed using inline-block (and width of at most 50% of the container, so they both can fit), see here:

```css
div {width: 40%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body> 
    <div>
      <h2>Members</h2> 
      <ul>
        <li>person_1</li>
        <li>person_2</li>
        <li>person_3</li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>1st shift</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>person_1</li>
        <li>person_2</li>
        <li>person_3</li>
        <li>person_4</li> 
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <br style="clear:both"> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can your solution handle more columns than just 2 ?

Comment: Ok. Also thanks for your fast and easy solution but the red frames are too fancy to not accept the code as correct answer ;-)

Comment: A valid argument is a valid argument - nothing I can do there! ;)

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
.text{
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.text ul{
  margin: 0;  
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/6ax77a5a/1/)